# Nested arrays are fetched from Odata but doesn't show on view

Tags: sapui5

I have created a fiori app and trying to fetch data using odata read function in controller.What is the right way to access data in view.
Backend request that works fine : /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZodatSRV/empSalesSet?$expand=set1,set2,set3,set4,set5&$filter=(category eq 'empSales')

View code that doesn't work :

```
<Text text="{/category}"></Text>
    <Text text="{empSalesSet/category}"></Text>
<Text text="{category}"></Text>
```

What is is right way to access data from the result set in view? Do i need do any specific binding on view? Please let me know what am i missing.

Controller code:

```
onInit: function () {

            var oDataModel = this.getView().getModel();
            var aFilter = [];
            var oFilter = {};

            oFilter = new Filter("category", FilterOperator.EQ, "empSales");
            aFilter = [oFilter];

            oDataModel.read("/empSalesSet", {
                urlParameters: {
                    "$expand": "set1,set2,set3,set4,set5"
                },
                filters: aFilter,
                success: function (data, response) {},
                error: function (oError) {}
            });

        }
```

In Chrome console i can see data coming as nested array in json format

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "",
                "uri": "",
                "type": "Znn"
            },
            "category": "empSales",
            "set1": {
                "results": []
            },
            "set2": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "",
                    "uri": "",
                    "type": "XXXXX"
                },
                "category": "todayTotal",
                "salesTotal": "",

                "marketingLineUpBestTotal": ""
            },
            "set3": {
                "results": [{
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "vv",
                        "uri": "bb",
                        "type": "nn"
                    },
                    "category": "mtd",
                    "employeeName": "A Marc",
                    "sales": "1203.23",
                    
                    "marketingLineUpBest": "5.000"
                }, {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "",
                        "uri": "",
                        "type": ""
                    },
                    "category": "cat",
                    "employeeName": "MUL2ECCDEV",
                    "sales": "0",
                    "marketingLine": "1"
                }]
            },
            "set4": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "",
                    "uri": "",
                    "type": ""
                },
                
                "salesTotal": "1203.23",
                
                "totalUnitsTotal": "5.000",
                "usedUnitsTotal": "0",
                "marketingLineUpBestTotal": "5.000"
            },
            "set5": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "",
                    "uri": "",
                    "type": ""
                },
                "category": "site",
                "site": "1002",
                "siteName": "106",
                "empSales": {
                    "__deferred": {
                        "uri": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

On the xml view what syntax should use to display data from set 3 array, set 4

Comment: Don't do `oDataModel.read`. Instead bind the view to the OData model path (`this.getView().bindElement(sPath)`). Then the third syntax `text="{category}"` should work.

Comment: Hi Marc,what should be spath here since i want to call entity set with expand and filter criteria.This is what i want to call in backend: sap/opu/odata/sap/ZodatSRV/empSalesSet?$expand=set1,set2,set3,set4,set5&$filter=(category eq 'empSales'). in front end i have 3 sap.m table where i need to fetch this data.each table has different id.

Comment: Then bind your table to the EntitySet. This can be done directly in the XML code. There you can also define `expand` and `filter` (but hardcoded). If expand and filter have to be dynamic you can just bind the Table to the EntitySet and do the expand and filter later in JS

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an array and not an object, so your read is in fact an OData query call.

The way to match the direct/absolute binding in this case should be:

```
<Text text="{empSalesSet/0/category}"></Text>
```

But you should really think about your real scenario. Normally query calls (GET method that returns an array of objects - calls the _GET_ENTITY_SET method on the OData service) should be binded to list controls (list, table, etc..) that show more than 1 result.

Comment: Hi Jose, This didnt work either.It still doesnt show any value

Comment: Hi Ria, not sure it can be done using the ODataModel. If your expand entities and filter values are always the same, I'd use @Marc suggestion of having it hardcoded on the xml. Although I don't think it will work for your case since you are getting a array and just want to use the first record. My solution for this case would be getting the data on the success function and save it has a local JSONModel and bind my view to this one.